# Transfer adoptable SD card to another ROM

Tags: custom-roms, encryption, 7.0-nougat, adoptable-storage, disk-encryption

Is it possible to use an adoptable SD card on another *ROM*, by copying the *encryption key* located at `/data/misc/vold/*.key`?

**According to the [Android documentation](https://source.android.com/devices/storage/adoptable) :**

> .. Keys are associated with adopted devices based on the adopted partition GUID.
> **..**
> Because the contents of an adopted storage device are strongly tied to the
>   Android device that adopted it, the encryption keys should not be extractable
>   from the parent device, and **therefore the storage device can't be mounted elsewhere.**

Apart from some errors that may be caused by the different ROM, **is it possible to access the SD card across ROMs?** Or is adoptable storage only accessible on the ROM it was *created with*?